# Unity 2019 gradle build failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, sdk

I noticed that a lot of people have had this issue but I haven't been able to find a solution to it yet.

The main other places I found with almost exactly the same error, and recently, is [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/no-internal-option-on-android-build.593887/)

When I simply try to install unity 2019.1 and the web GL editor component as well as the Android build component via the offline installer from the beta page, and attempt to build a basic empty scene to Android, after installing `NDK` and the `SDK` manually offline as well and pointing unity to the installations, then everything goes fine until the very end, but then it says "Gradle build failed..."

And there are about 26 errors that I can't copy now because I'm on a different device, but the main one is

`"Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0,.`

And then could not get resource HTTP (...gradle-3.2.0.pom, basically)

So that link I mentioned earlier involved almost the same issue, but it's still unresolved. Basically, the unity staff guy implied that it's not possible to completely install unity offline, you would at least need to connect to the internet once to allow unity to install gradle to the `home/.Gradle/cache`, OR you can do it on another computer that can have unity, then copy over the cache folder.

The problems are, first of all, that even for that other guy who DID install unity and build an Android project on another computer with internet, it still didn't work for other reasons, but I'm just wondering on my case (and any similar case) where I don't have another computer that can install unity online, and the only unity capable computer is offline only, and unity is supposed to able to be installed offline via the beta components at least anyway, so how can I get the Gradle components set up?

Does anyone know where I can find a download of 3.2.0 Gradle cache?

Or is there any other solution anyone knows of at all?

I don't want to have to export the project every time then rebuild it in Android studio